# How to pass GPIO status in a thread using def with args

Tags: gpio

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time
    import threading
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
    def fun1(a,b,c):
        mycount = 0
        while my count < c
             GPIO.output(a, True)
             time.sleep(b)
             GPIO.output(a, False)
             time.sleep(b)
             mycount=mycount +1
   
   thread1=threading.Target(target = fun1, args = (11,1,2)
   thread1.start()
```

Code returns an error from Threading module saying GPIO.setup(a,GPIO.OUT) not valid as GPIO.BOARD etc not defined. How to pass GPIO status to the threading module? Works OK if called outside a thread.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted is not valid.

The following works for me using python 3.7.3. You do get a warning about pin re-use but that is normal.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import threading
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)

def fun1(a,b,c):
    print(a,b,c)
    mycount = 0
    while mycount < c:
         GPIO.output(a, True)
         time.sleep(b)
         GPIO.output(a, False)
         time.sleep(b)
         mycount=mycount +1

thread1=threading.Thread(target = fun1, args = (11,1,2))
thread1.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I have now worked out the solution by creating a Class FLASHLED and passing args  for pin, delay and cycles to it using self. Works without any error messages to run two leds or more all on different GPIO pins. Main code can still run while these flash in the threads. I can share the code if you wish.

Comment: @Stefan24 Please create an answer for your solution and mark it as the accepted one after two days with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Comment: Cannot post solution as advised my question is off topic - not raspberrypi specific. Pity as a really helpful piece of code I am sure lots of raspberrypi users would find helpful.